# Trying to use netlib code (QUADPACK). What is xerror?

Tags: fortran, gfortran, numerical-methods

I'm trying to figure out how to use [quadpack](http://www.netlib.org/quadpack/).

In a single folder, I located the contents of "[qag.f plus dependencies](http://www.netlib.org/cgi-bin/netlibfiles.pl?filename=/quadpack/qag.f)" and the code blow as qag_test.f:

(maybe this code itself is not very important. This is in fact just a snippet from the [quadpack document](http://www.netlib.org/quadpack/doc))

```
      REAL A,ABSERR,B,EPSABS,EPSREL,F,RESULT,WORK
      INTEGER IER,IWORK,KEY,LAST,LENW,LIMIT,NEVAL
      DIMENSION IWORK(100),WORK(400)
      EXTERNAL F
      A = 0.0E0
      B = 1.0E0
      EPSABS = 0.0E0
      EPSREL = 1.0E-3
      KEY = 6
      LIMIT = 100
      LENW = LIMIT*4
      CALL QAG(F,A,B,EPSABS,EPSREL,KEY,RESULT,ABSERR,NEVAL,
     *  IER,LIMIT,LENW,LAST,IWORK,WORK)
C  INCLUDE WRITE STATEMENTS
      STOP
      END
C
      REAL FUNCTION F(X)
      REAL X
      F = 2.0E0/(2.0E0+SIN(31.41592653589793E0*X))
      RETURN
      END
```

Using `gfortran *.f` (installed as MinGW 64bit), I got:

```
C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\ccIQwFEt.o:qag.f:(.text+0x1e0): undefined re
ference to `xerror_'
C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\cc6XR3D0.o:qage.f:(.text+0x83): undefined re
ference to `r1mach_'
(and a lot more of the same r1mach_ error)
```

It seems [r1mach is a part of BLAS](http://www.netlib.org/blas/) (and I don't know why it's not packaged in [here](http://www.netlib.no/netlib/blas/blas.tgz) but obtained as "auxiliary"), but what is xerror?

How do I properly compile this snippet in my environment, Win7 64bit (hopefully without Cygwin)?

Your help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

xerror is an error reporting routine.  Looking at the way it is called, it appears to use Hollerith constants (the ones where `"foo"` is written as `3hfoo`).

```
      if(ier.ne.0) call xerror(26habnormal return from  qag ,
     *  26,ier,lvl)
```

xerror in turn calls xerrwv, passing along the arguments (plus a few more).

This was definitely written before Fortran 77 became widespread.

Your best bet would be to use a compiler which still supports Hollerith constants, pull in all the dependencies (xeerwv has a few more, I don't know why you didn't get them from netlib) and run it through the compiler of your choice. Most compilers, including gfortran, support Hollerith; just ignore the warnings :-)

You will possibly need to modify one routine, that is xerprt.  With gfortran, you could write this one as

```
subroutine xerprt(c,n)
  character(len=1), dimension(n) :: c
  write (*,'(500A)') c
end subroutine xerprt
```

and put this one into a separate file so that the compiler doesn't catch the rank violation (I know, I know...)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Are xerror and more available from netlib? Where is it (I can't find it), or is there actually a better way to locate/install all the dependencies at once? I'm so sorry, this is the first time for me to use netlib.

Comment: Search for xerror from http://netlib.org/cgi-bin/search.pl , this will give you the link to http://netlib.org/alliant/quad/xerror.f .