# How to use quadpack with Microsoft Visual Studio (Intel Fortran) ? Errors in xerrmv.f

Tags: fortran, intel-fortran

I am trying to use quadpack in Microsoft Visual using Intel Fortran.
From  [netlib](http://netlib.org/alliant/quad/) I downloaded: dqag.f, dqage.f, dqk15.f, dqk21.f, dqk31.f, dqk41.f, dqk51.f, dqk61.f, dqpsrt.f, dquad.f, fdump.f, j4save.f, s88fmt.f, testf4.f, xerabt.f, xerctl.f, xerprt.f, xerror.f, xerrwv.f, xersav.f, xgetua.f.
to try to recreate the result from [makefile.2](http://netlib.org/alliant/quad/makefile.2).
And I get the errors:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       Compilation Aborted (code 1)        C:\Users\...\test_quadpack\xerrwv.f 1   
Error       error #6633: The type of the actual argument differs from the type of the dummy argument.   [LFIRST]        C:\Users\...\test_quadpack\xerrwv.f 65  
Error       error #6633: The type of the actual argument differs from the type of the dummy argument.   [MESSG]     C:\Users\...\test_quadpack\xerrwv.f 127 
Error       error #6634: The shape matching rules of actual arguments and dummy arguments have been violated.   [MESSG]     C:\Users\C:\Users\...\test_quadpack\xerrwv.f    127
```

These errors I get from xerrmv.f which can be downloaded from [xerrmv.f](http://netlib.org/alliant/quad/xerrwv.f) line 65, 127 and 127

```
      subroutine xerrwv(messg,nmessg,nerr,level,ni,i1,i2,nr,r1,r2)
c
c     abstract
c        xerrwv processes a diagnostic message, in a manner
c        determined by the value of level and the current value
c        of the library error control flag, kontrl.
c        (see subroutine xsetf for details.)
c        in addition, up to two integer values and two real
c        values may be printed along with the message.
c
c     description of parameters
c      --input--
c        messg - the hollerith message to be processed.
c        nmessg- the actual number of characters in messg.
c        nerr  - the error number associated with this message.
c                nerr must not be zero.
c        level - error category.
c                =2 means this is an unconditionally fatal error.
c                =1 means this is a recoverable error.  (i.e., it is
c                   non-fatal if xsetf has been appropriately called.)
c                =0 means this is a warning message only.
c                =-1 means this is a warning message which is to be
c                   printed at most once, regardless of how many
c                   times this call is executed.
c        ni    - number of integer values to be printed. (o to 2)
c        i1    - first integer value.
c        i2    - second integer value.
c        nr    - number of real values to be printed. (0 to 2)
c        r1    - first real value.
c        r2    - second real value.
c
c     examples
c        call xerror(29hsmooth -- num (=i1) was zero.,29,1,2,
c    1   1,num,0,0,0.,0.)
c        call xerrwv(54hquadxy -- requested error (r1) less than minimum
c    1 (r2).,54,77,1,0,0,0,2,errreq,errmin)
c
c     written by ron jones, with slatec common math library subcommittee
c     latest revision ---  19 mar 1980
c
      dimension messg(nmessg),lun(5)
c     get flags
      lkntrl = j4save(2,0,.false.)
      maxmes = j4save(4,0,.false.)
c     check for valid input
      if ((nmessg.gt.0).and.(nerr.ne.0).and.
     1    (level.ge.(-1)).and.(level.le.2)) go to 10
         if (lkntrl.gt.0) call xerprt(17hfatal error in...,17)
         call xerprt(23hxerror -- invalid input,23)
         if (lkntrl.gt.0) call fdump
         if (lkntrl.gt.0) call xerprt(29hjob abort due to fatal error.,
     1   29)
         if (lkntrl.gt.0) call xersav(1h ,0,0,0,kdummy)
         call xerabt(23hxerror -- invalid input,23)
         return
   10 continue
c     record message
      junk = j4save(1,nerr,.true.)
      call xersav(messg,nmessg,nerr,level,kount)
c     let user override
      lfirst = messg(1)
      lmessg = nmessg
      lerr = nerr
      llevel = level
      call xerctl(lfirst,lmessg,lerr,llevel,lkntrl)
c     reset to original values
      lmessg = nmessg
      lerr = nerr
      llevel = level
      lkntrl = max0(-2,min0(2,lkntrl))
      mkntrl = iabs(lkntrl)
c     decide whether to print message
      if ((llevel.lt.2).and.(lkntrl.eq.0)) go to 100
      if (((llevel.eq.(-1)).and.(kount.gt.min0(1,maxmes)))
     1.or.((llevel.eq.0)   .and.(kount.gt.maxmes))
     2.or.((llevel.eq.1)   .and.(kount.gt.maxmes).and.(mkntrl.eq.1))
     3.or.((llevel.eq.2)   .and.(kount.gt.max0(1,maxmes)))) go to 100
         if (lkntrl.le.0) go to 20
            call xerprt(1h ,1)
c           introduction
            if (llevel.eq.(-1)) call xerprt
     1(57hwarning message...this message will only be printed once.,57)
            if (llevel.eq.0) call xerprt(13hwarning in...,13)
            if (llevel.eq.1) call xerprt
     1      (23hrecoverable error in...,23)
            if (llevel.eq.2) call xerprt(17hfatal error in...,17)
   20    continue
c        message
         call xerprt(messg,lmessg)
         call xgetua(lun,nunit)
         do 50 kunit=1,nunit
            iunit = lun(kunit)
            if (iunit.eq.0) iunit = i1mach(4)
            if (ni.ge.1) write (iunit,22) i1
            if (ni.ge.2) write (iunit,23) i2
            if (nr.ge.1) write (iunit,24) r1
            if (nr.ge.2) write (iunit,25) r2
   22       format (11x,21hin above message, i1=,i10)
   23       format (11x,21hin above message, i2=,i10)
   24       format (11x,21hin above message, r1=,e20.10)
   25       format (11x,21hin above message, r2=,e20.10)
            if (lkntrl.le.0) go to 40
c              error number
               write (iunit,30) lerr
   30          format (15h error number =,i10)
   40       continue
   50    continue
c        trace-back
         if (lkntrl.gt.0) call fdump
  100 continue
      ifatal = 0
      if ((llevel.eq.2).or.((llevel.eq.1).and.(mkntrl.eq.2)))
     1ifatal = 1
c     quit here if message is not fatal
      if (ifatal.le.0) return
      if ((lkntrl.le.0).or.(kount.gt.max0(1,maxmes))) go to 120
c        print reason for abort
         if (llevel.eq.1) call xerprt
     1   (35hjob abort due to unrecovered error.,35)
         if (llevel.eq.2) call xerprt
     1   (29hjob abort due to fatal error.,29)
c        print error summary
         call xersav(1h ,-1,0,0,kdummy)
  120 continue
c     abort
      if ((llevel.eq.2).and.(kount.gt.max0(1,maxmes))) lmessg = 0
      call xerabt(messg,lmessg)
      return
      end
```

This is the main program:

```
      program dquad
c driver for quadpack
      implicit double precision (a-h, o-z)
      external f
      parameter (limit=50, lenw=4*limit)
      dimension iwork(limit), work(lenw)
      open (unit=8, file='outquad', iostat=ios, err=100)
c lower limit of itegration
      a=-1.0d+00
c upper limit of integration
      b=2.0d+00
c absolute accuracy requested
      epsabs=1.0d-15
c relative accuracy requested
      epsrel=1.0d-09
      do 20 l=1, 3000
c key for choice of local integration rule: 
c     a Gauss-Kronrod pair is used with
c                7 - 15 points if key .lt. 2,
c               10 - 21 points if key  =   2,
c               15 - 31 points if key  =   3,
c               20 - 41 points if key  =   4,
c               25 - 51 points if key  =   5,
c               30 - 61 points if key .gt. 5
      do 10 key=1, 6
 
      call dqag (f, a, b, epsabs, epsrel, key, result, abserr, neval, 
     *           ier, limit, lenw, last, iwork, work)

      if (l .eq. 1) then
      write (8, *) 'integral                       =', result
      write (8, *) 'absolute error                 =', abserr
      write (8, *) 'number of integrand evaluations=', neval
      end if
   10 continue
   20 continue
      stop
      
  100 write (8, *) 'ios=', ios
      stop
 
      end
```

Also from netlib [quad.f](http://netlib.org/alliant/quad/dquad.f).
And this is the function that should be integrated, it's just an example, it not the function that I am gonna integrate in my research,
I just want to learn to integrate quadpack in my code.

```
        double precision function f(x)
    implicit double precision (a-h, o-z)

        f = 1.0d+00 + x * x + 1.0d+00 / (1.0d+00 + 1.0d+02 * x * x)

        return
    end
```

This is from netlib [testf4.f] (http://netlib.org/alliant/quad/testf4.f).

This is [xerctl.f](http://netlib.org/alliant/quad/xerctl.f)

```
   SUBROUTINE XERCTL(MESSG1,NMESSG,NERR,LEVEL,KONTRL)
C***BEGIN PROLOGUE  XERCTL
C***DATE WRITTEN   790801   (YYMMDD)
C***REVISION DATE  820801   (YYMMDD)
C***CATEGORY NO.  R3C
C***KEYWORDS  ERROR,XERROR PACKAGE
C***AUTHOR  JONES, R. E., (SNLA)
C***PURPOSE  Allows user control over handling of individual errors.
C***DESCRIPTION
C     Abstract
C        Allows user control over handling of individual errors.
C        Just after each message is recorded, but before it is
C        processed any further (i.e., before it is printed or
C        a decision to abort is made), a call is made to XERCTL.
C        If the user has provided his own version of XERCTL, he
C        can then override the value of KONTROL used in processing
C        this message by redefining its value.
C        KONTRL may be set to any value from -2 to 2.
C        The meanings for KONTRL are the same as in XSETF, except
C        that the value of KONTRL changes only for this message.
C        If KONTRL is set to a value outside the range from -2 to 2,
C        it will be moved back into that range.
C
C     Description of Parameters
C
C      --Input--
C        MESSG1 - the first word (only) of the error message.
C        NMESSG - same as in the call to XERROR or XERRWV.
C        NERR   - same as in the call to XERROR or XERRWV.
C        LEVEL  - same as in the call to XERROR or XERRWV.
C        KONTRL - the current value of the control flag as set
C                 by a call to XSETF.
C
C      --Output--
C        KONTRL - the new value of KONTRL.  If KONTRL is not
C                 defined, it will remain at its original value.
C                 This changed value of control affects only
C                 the current occurrence of the current message.
C***REFERENCES  JONES R.E., KAHANER D.K., "XERROR, THE SLATEC ERROR-
C                 HANDLING PACKAGE", SAND82-0800, SANDIA LABORATORIES,
C                 1982.
C***ROUTINES CALLED  (NONE)
C***END PROLOGUE  XERCTL
      CHARACTER*20 MESSG1
C***FIRST EXECUTABLE STATEMENT  XERCTL
      RETURN
      END
```

This is [xerror.f](http://netlib.org/alliant/quad/xerror.f)

```
      subroutine xerror(messg,nmessg,nerr,level)
c
c     abstract
c        xerror processes a diagnostic message, in a manner
c        determined by the value of level and the current value
c        of the library error control flag, kontrl.
c        (see subroutine xsetf for details.)
c
c     description of parameters
c      --input--
c        messg - the hollerith message to be processed, containing
c                no more than 72 characters.
c        nmessg- the actual number of characters in messg.
c        nerr  - the error number associated with this message.
c                nerr must not be zero.
c        level - error category.
c                =2 means this is an unconditionally fatal error.
c                =1 means this is a recoverable error.  (i.e., it is
c                   non-fatal if xsetf has been appropriately called.)
c                =0 means this is a warning message only.
c                =-1 means this is a warning message which is to be
c                   printed at most once, regardless of how many
c                   times this call is executed.
c
c     examples
c        call xerror(23hsmooth -- num was zero.,23,1,2)
c        call xerror(43hinteg  -- less than full accuracy achieved.,
c                    43,2,1)
c        call xerror(65hrooter -- actual zero of f found before interval
c    1 fully collapsed.,65,3,0)
c        call xerror(39hexp    -- underflows being set to zero.,39,1,-1)
c
c     written by ron jones, with slatec common math library subcommittee
c     latest revision ---  7 feb 1979
c
      dimension messg(nmessg)
      call xerrwv(messg,nmessg,nerr,level,0,0,0,0,0.,0.)
      return
      end
```

I think the problem is with the messages like this from here:

```
  if(ier.ne.0) call xerror(26habnormal return from dqag ,26,ier,lvl)
```

but I don't know to fix it.
Can I use in main Fortran 90, where I call the subroutine to integrate? How it is supposed to look? I'm not familiar with fortran 77.
Any suggestion for dealing with this is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You really should show the full error output, not just those three lines. You must tell us which source file does this error message and which line is indicated. See [mcve].

Comment: I added the lines and the source file. Thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: But I asked for the full output. See [ask]. Do not just aelect some lines, do a full copy-paste. Show the relevant source *within your question itself*. See [mcve].

Comment: Thank you for the error messages, now please also show the relevant code. That means the code that calls those subrouines, including the declarations of the relevant variables, and the declaration part of the code of those subroutines.

Comment: I do not think your main program matters here, rather some unsound or obsolete code in the library itself.

Comment: Forget Fortran 90, even Fortran 77 decided `call xerror(26h...` was a mistake.

Comment: This answer mentions the problem with those Holleriths https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28524278/trying-to-use-netlib-code-quadpack-what-is-xerror